# setting a variable before an if statement ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

I am working using rails and I have a class from activerecord called Car. In the application that I am building,The application  let's the user add a new car in one the pages or if not they can choose the one that it's already there.

I am having difficulties trying to come up with a solution, although both of them work it would only execute until some part of code because it's in an if/else statement.

ad_group_controllers.rb

```
if params[:ad_group][:file]
        @car = Car.create(year: params[:ad_group][:car][:year],model: params[:model],make_id: params[:make], trim: params[:trim])
        @car.update(file: params[:ad_group][:file])
        @ad_group.car = @car
    else
        @car = Car.find(params[:ad_group][:car][:id])
        @trim = params[:trim] == 'none' ? nil : params[:trim]
        @promotional_logo = params[:promotional_logo].blank? || params[:promotional_logo].downcase == 'none' || params[:promotional_logo] == '0' ? nil : PromotionalLogo.find(params[:promotional_logo])
        if (@promotional_logo && @ad_group.promotional_logo.nil?) || (@promotional_logo.nil? && @ad_group.promotional_logo)
            @ad_group.promotional_logo = @promotional_logo
            @ad_group.adjust_for_promotional_logo
        end
        @ad_group.update_attributes(make: @make, car: @car, trim: @trim, client: @client, rollover: params[:ad_group][:rollover], promotional_logo: @promotional_logo || nil)
        AdGroup.fields.each do |field|
            @ad_group[field] = params[:ad_group][field]
        end
    end
    @ad_group.ads.each do |ad|
        url = @ad_group.car.file.blank? ? nil : @ad_group.car.file.url
        car = @ad_group.car.file.blank? ? nil : @ad_group.car
        ad.images.find_by(name: 'car').update(url: url, car: car)

        url = @ad_group.promotional_logo.blank? ? nil : @ad_group.promotional_logo.file.url
        logo = @ad_group.promotional_logo.blank? ? nil : @ad_group.promotional_logo
        ad.images.find_by(name: "promotional_logo").update(url: url, promotional_logo: logo)

        ad.texts.find_by(name: "client_name").update(content: @client.name)

        if @ad_group.car.blank?
            car_name = ''
        else
            car_name = "#{@car.year} #{@make.name} #{@car.model}"
            car_name += " #{@car.trim}" unless params[:trim] == 'none' || params[:trim].blank?
        end
        ad.texts.find_by(name: "car_name").update(content: car_name)
```

Basically the if statement it's stating that if's there is a file in the adgroup paramaters create a car, and if not it should stay as

```
@car = Car.find(params[:ad_group][:car][:id])
```

the code below that has to execute for both cases. what is the best way to do this without repeating the code in the if and the else.

Comment: do you mean the code below `@car = Car.find(params[:ad_group][:car][:id])` has to be executed for both cases ?, if so, just put it outside the `if` right after the `end` that closes the `if` statement. Btw, it would be good if you clean up that controller, it has a lot of lines of code.

Comment: @fanta sorry i meant that  if there is a file, a new car should be created and if not it just stays as car= Car.find(params[:ad_group][:car][:id]). Since i am using car in a lot of places I need to change it's value depending of the user's input. although I can't since it's inside the if/else. We are in the process of cleaning the controller  up.

Comment: ok, so, I didn't get which code should be executed after the `@car = Car.find(params[:ad_group][:car][:id])` line. Right now, with the code you have, you're setting the `@car` variable in two different ways, one sets it to a new `Car` and the other one uses the existing `Car`, so, in both cases you're setting the `@car` variable. What else do you need ?.

Comment: @fanta all the code below that line needs to be executed in both cases when a new car it's created, or when there it's an existing one. Right now it only executing when there is an existing one. I don't want to repeat the same code twice.

Comment: Ok, then remove all the lines starting from `@trim = params[:trim] == 'none' ? nil : params[:trim]` to the `end` that closes the `AdGroup.fields.each do |field|` block, and put them outside the `if` statement, but put all that code after the `end` that closes the `if`, not before the `if`. UPDATE: I guess it's easier if I say that you should put all those lines I mentioned right before the `@ad_group.ads.each do |ad|` line.